# Powershell: help me stop flashing! Clear-Host blink

Tags: powershell, console

I'm putting together a little demo where I want one console window to show a current status. Here's my first iteration:

```
clear-host; while (1 -eq 1) { git log --graph --oneline; start-sleep -s 1; clear}
```

Unfortunately, this results in the text "flashing" on the screen every second as the screen clears, then is replaced with the next result. No only is the aesthetically unpleasing, it is albeit rare, potentially dangerous for some unsuspecting viewers. So my next try was this:

```
clear-host; while (1 -eq 1) { git log --graph --oneline; start-sleep -s 1; [Console]::CursorTop=0;[Console]::CursorLeft=0;}
```

There is no flash now, but longer lines are not cleared just drag down the screen.

Can anyone think of a way to get the best of both worlds? Clear the screen when I have too, but no repeating blink?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to continue along the path of console cursor manipulation, but PowerShell is not specifically designed for this scenario.

A far better alternative is to use `Write-Progress` to show real progress information.

```
$activity = "Git 'er done"

for() {
    $result = & git log --graph --oneline
    Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Id 1 -Status ($result -join ', ')
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
Write-Progress -Activity $activity -Id 1 -Completed
```

(season to taste)

The reason I'm `-join`ing `$result` is that on a repo of mine, the git command itself returns 3 lines, and `$result` is an array. You may want to decide how you handle that for your specific case, but be aware that `$result` *can* be an array and `Write-Progress` won't accept one.

#### Other Considerations

`Write-Progress` shows a graphical progress bar in ISE, but shows a text-based progress bar in the console host (`powershell.exe`) and in PowerShell Web Access. To put that another way, the specific PowerShell *host application* determines how the information is displayed, but it's available in a supported, defined way.

That means that `Write-Progress` should work in any environment (it may result in nothing happening, or display nothing, but it shouldn't crash).

In contrast, direct console manipulation probably only works in ISE and console host (admittedly they are probably the only hosts you care about), but if your code were suddenly hosted in a runspace in some C# application, it could just error out (I actually have no idea).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The blink is gone. Unfortunately, so the the ascii art graph that I was hoping for.   I'm looking to see if I can get a multi line version of write-progress, but it's not looking good so far.

Comment: @Rob both the `-Status` and `-CurrentOperation` show information, but they don't support newlines. When I tried `git log --graph` it accepted the parameter but I don't see any kind of ASCII art in my output, so I didn't take it into account.

Comment: Yeah the branching ascii is on the left. It's more pronounced when there are a lot of branches and easier to see with the --oneline switch.   I didn't realize I had the requirement until I tried your solution. :)